# Assign value of enum to some other variable

Tags: delphi, enums

I have the following enum in Delphi:

```
type TChangingDataSetState=(Inserting=1,Editing,Deleting)
......
var
ChangingDSSsate:TChangingDataSetState;
```

In BeforePost event I check if the dataset in Insert mode then I

```
 ChangingDSState:=Inserting
else
 ChagingDSState:=Editing
```

Let's say the dataset is in edit mode, it means my ChangingDSState var will get evuluated to 2(Editing). Now I want to know how I can then use that number to pass it as an argument to a procedure

Comment: Are you sure you need the `=1` inside the declaration of `TChangingDataSetState`?

Comment: If he doesn't, the enumeration starts with ordinal value 0.

Comment: +1 For the `TChangingDataSetState=(Inserting=1` part, didn't know you can force the enumeration values like this, pretty cool, when was this introduced ?

Comment: @Johan: AFAIK it was introduced for Linux compatibility, i.e. with D6/7.

Comment: @HeartWare: Exactly. The `=1` introduces non-standard behaviour he possibly doesn't need. And **if** he doen't need it he might circumvent some issues be sticking to idiomatic use.

Comment: @Johan, explicit ordinality of enum was introduced in D6 to be exact.

Comment: Is there a reason to use an integer rather than the enumeration as the parameter? (E.g third party code)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume you want the ordinal value rather than the enumerated value. You get that with `ord()`.

So, `ord(ChagingDSState)` is an integer expression with a value of `2` when `ChagingDSState` equals `Editing`.

Comment: Thank yo body. I'll vote the answer up in 8 minutes as i can't know. OK?:))

Comment: +1 for using `Ord(ChagingDSState)`, rather than casting to integer `Integer(ChagingDSState)`